# how should I create this one

Tags: javascript

My goal is to make my output like this 
Conditions 
Compute for the tax of the three employees.
Condition to compute tax :  (single and salary > 30,000)  tax is 10% of the salary.
(single and salary > 40,000)  tax is 15% of the salary.
else tax is 5% of the salary
Sample Output :

Employee Name 1 : James Reyes

Salary : 50,000

Status : Single

Tax : ______

Employee Name 2 : Leo Martinez

Salary : 25,000

Status : Married

Tax : ______

Employee Name 3 : Efren Cordova

Salary : 35000

Status : Single

Tax : ______

This is my code

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>A Javascript Sample</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var linebreak = "<br />";

    var myname = "james";

    if (myname == "james") {
      console.log("Employee Name is James Reyes");
      document.write("<b>Employee Name is James Reyes</b>");
      document.write(linebreak);
    } else if (myname == "leo") {
      console.log("Employee Name is Leo Martinez ");
      document.write("<b>Employee Name is Leo Martinez </b>");
      document.write(linebreak);
    } else if (myname == "Efren") {
      console.log("Employee Name is Efren Cordova");
      document.write("<b>Employee Name is Efren Cordova</b>");
      document.write(linebreak);
    } else {
      console.log("Unknown");
      document.write("<b>Unknown</b>");
      document.write(linebreak);
    }

    var salary = 50000;


    if (salary > 30000) {
      console.log("You are qualified for 10% tax");
      document.write("<b>You are qualified for 10% tax</b>");
      document.write(linebreak);
    } else if (salary > 40000) {

      console.log("You are qualified for 15% tax");
      document.write("<b>You are qualified for 15% tax</b>");
      document.write(linebreak);
    } else {
      console.log("No tax to be deducted");
      document.write("<b>No tax to be deducted</b>");
      document.write(linebreak);
    }
    var status = "Married";

    if (status == "single") {
      console.log();
      document.write("<b>Single</b>");
      document.write(linebreak);

    } else if (status == "Married") {
      console.log("Married");
      document.write("<b>Married</b>");
      document.write(linebreak);
    }

    <!-------TAX INPUT---->
  </script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome!
May I suggest "think objects" and "think functions"?
You have a list (an array) of **people**.
Each of those is a **person**.
Each of those has a **name**, **salary**, and **status**, and you need to figure out their **tax** bracket.
You need a mechanism (function) that takes in **salary** and **status** and puts out (return(s)) the **tax** bracket.
Then, you iterate the **people*, and format-print their information.
Get started, add/modify question, and we'll help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you have x number of employees (I'm going to use your sample input of 3). Each employee has 4 properties (as far as what you've described): name, salary, status and tax. You need to calculate the tax each employee will owe based on their status and salary.

Here's one way I would do it:

```
const body = document.querySelector('body')
const taxContainer = document.createElement('div')
const employees = [{
    name: 'James Reyes',
    status: 'single',
    salary: 50000,
  },
  {
    name: 'Leo Martinez',
    status: 'single',
    salary: 25000,
  },
  {
    name: 'Efren Cordova',
    status: 'single',
    salary: 35000,
  }
]

const calculateTaxes = (employee = {}) => {
  const {
    salary = 0
  } = employee
  if (salary > 30000 && salary < 40000) {
    return parseFloat(salary * .10)
  } else if (salary > 40000) {
    return parseFloat(salary * .15)
  } else {
    return parseFloat(salary * .05)
  }
}

for (let employee of employees) {
  const taxItem = document.createElement('div')
  const nameHeader = document.createElement('h1')
  const taxes = document.createElement('p')
  nameHeader.innerText = employee.name
  employee.tax = calculateTaxes(employee)
  taxes.innerText = employee.tax
  taxItem.appendChild(nameHeader)
  taxItem.appendChild(taxes)
  taxContainer.appendChild(taxItem)
}
body.appendChild(taxContainer)
```